# Select table row and keep highlighted using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap table with clickable rows that are highlighted when hovered over (I can get rid of the hover feature if it makes this easier). I want the selected row to remain highlighted until another row is clicked or it is reclicked.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
            //  console.log("test ");                   
        });
```

and the table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr class='clickable-row'>
```

I tried this code in the JS but didn't work

```
$(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You are quite close. Targeting the `.clickable-row` class on your `$("#myTable").on(...)` event and using Bootstrap's `.active` class should work for you:

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
  <tr class="clickable-row">
    <th>Example</th>
  </tr>
   <tr class="clickable-row">
    <th>Example 2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

And a [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/LypuKDbNCu)

Note: If you left `.table-hover` on your table, you'd have to use a different class than `.active`, such as `.bg-info` (which would be a [blue  hightlight](http://www.bootply.com/hyRUHmocrd))

To remove a highlight from the row (ie click again), check if the row has the class and remove it:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

See @BravoZulu's answer for original information.

Comment: re-clicking on the row does not deselect it.

Comment: There is a bug with this solution - you can select _multiple_ rows (one per page, to be precise). Using `table.$('tr.active').removeClass('active');`  seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("highlight"))
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    else
        $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
})
```

Comment: This is where toggleClass is handy.

Answer (score 2):

To show the painted row of a color, indicating that it is selected, you can use  `data-row-style = 'formatterRowUtSelect'`

Inside your code, you can add this method:

```
formatterRowUtSelect = function (row, index) {
    if (row.fieldOfMyObject == $ ('#fieldOfMyObject'). val ())
        return {classes: 'row-selected'};
    return {};
}
```

Do not forget to create the css for the selected row:

```
.row-selected {
    background-color: #a9f0ff !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I hope it serves you, Greetings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't already, please feel free to check out [how to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/ask) and [what's on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also, I'll note that it's generally more idiomatic that you use function declarations (i.e. `function foo() { ... }`) rather than implicit global assignment (like `foo = function () { ... }`). An added benefit to doing it this way is that [it also works in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Answer (score 0):

i have used this script on bootstrap-table.

```
$('#tb-pegawai').on('change', 'tr' , function (event) {
            if($('.selected')){ // } })
```